# ETH wallet error

Tags: go-ethereum, wallets

I want to download the ETH wallet and make light synchronization on my PC. I downloaded ethereum wallet, but after launch, the Checksum mismatch in downloaded node crashes! MD5: 308 ... Please install the geth version 1.8.23 manually

Comment: can any1 help me?

Comment: What happened after you installed geth 1.8.23 manually?

Comment: Have you tried re-installing?

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me.
You have to download the Geth version 1.8.23 from [here](https://geth.ethereum.org/downloads/) then you have to go to C:\Users\$YOUR_USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\EthereumWallet\binaries\Geth\unpacked, If you don't have a folder named unpacked then create. Paste the downloaded Geth.exe in this folder and launch ethereum wallet.

Answer (score 0):

does 1.8.23 work for today?? i try 1.8.23 but sync stuck, software node is empty. A higher geth version caus error -- Please install the geth version 1.8.23 manually

Comment: You won't be able to sync with mainnet since there were several forks between v1.8.23 and the latest release. Ethereum Wallet was deprecated several years ago it is better to use a different wallet, Metamask, MyCrypto and MyEtherWallet are well known wallets.